# Reason behind ZnO color

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, color

Why is zinc oxide yellow when hot and white when cold?

Is it yellow because of the flame used to make it hot?

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! There is a search function on this site, please feel free to give it a try ;)

Comment: @KlausWarzecha Admittedly, even though I was sure I'd read a zinc oxide colour question before, I couldn't find it myself after a quick search! Unfortunately the SE search function is not stellar.

Comment: @NicolauSakerNeto I simply entered ZnO and could find the question. But I also remembered that I had answered it :D

Comment: @Nicolau Apparently the search function is the worst thing about SE for many people. They're really trying hard to improve it.

Comment: Sorry. It didn't show up in the search. And thank you for the link. @KlausWarzecha